# Converting between ranges of numbers?

Tags: python, numbers, range

I'm using the following method to convert from one Range to another Range of numbers

```
def pos(self, value) :
    return int( math.floor(self.nitems * ((value - self.vmin)/float(self.vrange)) ) )
```

the problem is that it is not doing it consistently i.e. for a

```
 min-max/range : 10-100/90
 nitems : 100
```

i.e :

```
 10-100 => 0-100
```

i get gaps : missing : -1,19,29,39,49,....,99,100

```
 In [66]: np.array([ne.pos(x) for x in range(100)])                                                                                                                           
 Out[66]: array([-12, -10,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -2,   0,   1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,  16,  17,  18,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,
    25,  26,  27,  28,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  40,  41,  42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,  55,  56,  57,  58,  60,  61,
    62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,  68,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  80,  81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  90,  91,  92,  93,  94,  95,  96,  97,
    98])
```

Where is my error in the formula ? if there is consistent way to do it with any range ?
Is it because of the roundings ?

It has to "land" on every value in my target-range! and it has to be sequential.

---

hmm... now that I think about it may be it is not possible when the input range is smaller than the output range, unless I allow for real-numbers ?

it seems so, when i try with float no gaps :

```
 In [82]: np.array([ne.pos(x) for x in np.linspace(0,101,150)])                                                                                                               
 Out[82]: array([-12, -11, -10,  -9,  -9,  -8,  -7,  -6,  -6,  -5,  -4,  -3,  -3,  -2,  -1,   0,   0,   1,   2,   3,   3,   4,   5,   6,   6,   7,   8,   9,   9,  10,  11,  12,  12,
    13,  14,  15,  16,  16,  17,  18,  19,  19,  20,  21,  22,  22,  23,  24,  25,  25,  26,  27,  28,  28,  29,  30,  31,  31,  32,  33,  34,  34,  35,  36,  37,  37,
    38,  39,  40,  40,  41,  42,  43,  43,  44,  45,  46,  46,  47,  48,  49,  49,  50,  51,  52,  52,  53,  54,  55,  55,  56,  57,  58,  58,  59,  60,  61,  61,  62,
    63,  64,  64,  65,  66,  67,  67,  68,  69,  70,  70,  71,  72,  73,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  77,  78,  79,  80,  80,  81,  82,  83,  83,  84,  85,  86,  86,  87,
    88,  89,  89,  90,  91,  92,  92,  93,  94,  95,  95,  96,  97,  98,  98,  99, 100, 101])
```

Comment: Could you add a small example input/output?

Comment: the example  is in the post i.e.  in 0-100 => [..the array..] i.e  0 => -12, 1 => -10.... 99=>98

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you are over-complicating this, if all you're trying to do is create a second range of integers that is the same length but different starting point as the first range.

```
a = range(10, 100)
len(a) == 90
list(a) == [10, 11, 12, ..., 98, 99]

b = range(0, len(a))
len(b) == 90
list(b) == [0, 1, 2, ..., 88, 89]

c = range(20, 20 + len(a))
len(c) == 90
list(c) == [20, 21, 22, ..., 108, 109]
```

Comment: no.. both ranges can be any range ... this was just example .. it could be : 50-455, 32-890, 0-333 ... etc